# Auto-scale content to match its wrapper's area by using transform with CSS3

Tags: html, css, transform, zooming, scale

I have one `DIV` used as placeholder, with aspect ratio 8:1, styled this way

```
.out-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 12.5%;
}
```

There's another absolute `DIV` inside, with same aspect ratio

```
.in-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Inside `.in-wrap` element is another 8:1 `DIV` (*.content*) which is **always 640x80px**.

```
.content {
  width: 640px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

In `HTML` it looks this way

```
<div class="out-wrap">
  <div class="in-wrap">
    <div class="content">
      <!-- ... anything ... -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: Element `.content` may have anything inside, not just images.

Can I make `.content` scaled to fully fit `.in-wrap` area by using CSS3 `transform` property?

I've already tried playing with [scale()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) function with support of [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function and [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) property but with no any success. I can achieve this by using JavaScript but wondering is it possible by CSS only.

Comment: a scale with distortion?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don't understand what you mean by that

Comment: you need to fill all the space exactly (width and height need to scale differently == distortion) or to fill the space with overflow (width and height need to scale the same == no distortion)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ah that. No, already mentioned that all three containers are in same aspect ratio (8:1) so both, width and height should have same scaling value.